# AttributeError:'list' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, tensorflow

Here I am jus extracting a csv file and reading the "TV"values, calculating average and printing using tensorflow. But I am getting "AttributError" list has no attribute 'size' ". Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 import pandas
 csv = pandas.read_csv("Advertising.csv")["TV"]
 t = tf.constant(list(csv))
 r = tf.reduce_mean(t)
 sess = tf.Session()
 s = list(csv).size
 fill = tf.fill([s],r)
 f = sess.run(fill)
 print(f)
```

Comment: Try this: `s = len(csv)` instead of `s = list(csv).size`

Comment: Nope, lists don't have an attribute `size`. The normal way to get the length of a sized object is to use `len(object)` instead.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters.     In that case it gives the result [147.04249573  147.04249573  147.04249573  147.04249573  147.04249573  147.04249573  147.04249573  147.04249573  147.04249573  147.04249573........................]

Comment: @MaxU It displays like the result as above

Comment: @Raghavi: then please do include sample data and expected outcomes. If you have a pandas `Series` object, then just use the [`.size` attribute](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.size.html#pandas.Series.size) on that directly. Pandas and numpy translate most actions into actions on the contents, which is why they are an exception to the normal `len()` usage.

Comment: @Raghavi, `pandas.read_csv("Advertising.csv")["TV"]` returns a Pandas.Series object and `len(Pandas.Series)` returns its length. I can't imagine how can it return a list...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As summary of the discussion in the comments, here are valid ways of getting a length of the column in `csv`:

```
$ csv = pandas.read_csv("Advertising.csv")
$ print type(csv), len(csv)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 10

$ series = csv["TV"]
$ print type(series), len(series)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> 10

$ as_list = list(series)
$ print type(as_list), len(as_list)
<type 'list'> 10
```

And here's how to calculate the average (without tensorflow session):

```
$ import numpy as np
$ print np.mean(series)
1.2
```